# How to add new node to existing XML

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I have a trouble in adding new node in existing xml. So I have this code for creating first element

Here I setting fields

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;


@XmlRootElement (name = "books")
class Books { 
    private ArrayList<Book> books;
    public Books(){
        books = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void add(Book book){
        books.add(book);
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "book")
    public List<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "Book")
class Book {
    // поля
    @XmlAttribute(name="ganre") 
            String ganre;
    @XmlElement
    String bookName;
    @XmlElement
    String bookAuthor;
    @XmlElement
    int bookId;
    @XmlElement
    int bookYear;
    @XmlElement
    boolean bookAvailable;

    public Book(){

    }

    public Book(String ganre, int bookId, String bookName, String bookAuthor, int bookYear, boolean bookAvailable){ // Конструктор чтобы быстрее создавать новые книги не напрягаясь
        setGanre(ganre);
        setBookId(bookId);
        setBookName(bookName);
        setBookAuthor(bookAuthor);
        setBookYear(bookYear);
        setBookAvailable(bookAvailable);
    }

    String getGanre(){ 
        return this.ganre;
    }

    void setGanre(String ganre){ 
        this.ganre = ganre;
    }

    String getBookName(){
        return this.bookName;
    }

    void setBookName(String bookName){
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    String getBookAuthor (){
        return this.bookAuthor ;
    }

    void setBookAuthor (String bookAuthor ){
        this.bookAuthor  = bookAuthor;
    }

    boolean getBookAvailable(){
        return this.bookAvailable;
    }

    void setBookAvailable(boolean bookAvailable){
        this.bookAvailable = bookAvailable;
    }

    int getBookId(){
        return this.bookId;
    }

    void setBookId(int bookId){
        this.bookId = bookId;
    }

    int getBookYear(){
        return this.bookYear;
    }


    void setBookYear(int bookYear){
        this.bookYear = bookYear;
    }
}
```

Here I creating node

```
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestingTest {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, JAXBException {
        File file = new File("D:\\books.xml"); 
        Books bks = new Books(); 
        bks.add(new Book( 
                "fantasy",
                7111,
                "Tron",
                "Brawm",
                15,
                true
        ));

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Books.class); 
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); 
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(bks,file); 

}}
```

So Im trying to make rewrite existing file and add a new node in the end but always just rewriting the first node

intput

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<books>
    <book ganre="fantasy">
        <bookName>Tron</bookName>
        <bookAuthor>Brawm</bookAuthor>
        <bookId>7111</bookId>
        <bookYear>15</bookYear>
        <bookAvailable>true</bookAvailable>
    </book>
```

what I want to see after

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<books>
    <book ganre="fantasy">
        <bookName>Tron</bookName>
        <bookAuthor>Brawm</bookAuthor>
        <bookId>7111</bookId>
        <bookYear>15</bookYear>
        <bookAvailable>true</bookAvailable>
    </book>
    <book ganre="action">
        <bookName>Corn</bookName>
        <bookAuthor>Down</bookAuthor>
        <bookId>312</bookId>
        <bookYear>23</bookYear>
        <bookAvailable>false</bookAvailable>
    </book>
</books>
```

Comment: It would be useful to add the actual XML and the result XML you want to achieve. Also I don't see where you read and unmarshal the existing XML.

Comment: added result and what i whant to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your code you use the file for write only operations.

What you need to do is unmarshall the current content, add the book entry and marshall it back.

```
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Books books = (Books) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
books.add(book);
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(bks,file);
```

Frank.

Answer (score 0):

To add your new book to your existing file you first have to unmarshal the XML:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance( Books.class );
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
 Books books = (Books) unmarshaller.unmarshal( xmlFile );
```

After this you have to add the new book to your the list in Books:

```
List<Book> bookList = books.getBooks();
bookList.add( newBook );
```

Now you can marshal this modified Books like you already have done with the new one:

```
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal( books, xmlFile );
```